# Merge two Panda rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need help getting two rows in the same datafram merged/joined.

[image]

The first table is the df that I have right now
The second one is the one that I would like to have

I need to combine Jim and Bill. I don't want to overwrite values in either tables. I just want to update NaN values in the row (Bill) with the values with row(Jim) e.g city

There are about 20 columns that I need updating because of that I cannot just update the Bill/City cell

Thanks

Comment: Could you also post the expected outcome? It would help everyone here to properly tell you what should be done? Thanks. Just edit and add the expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
df.loc['Bill'] = df.loc['Bill'].fillna(df.loc['Jim'])
# or
df.loc['Bill'].fillna(df.loc['Jim'], inplace=True)
```